# AVPlayer freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

I use a AVPlayer for playing remote mp4 files, recently I received some bug reports, some users（with iOS 10.0 & iOS 10.1 devices）said that the player may freeze sometimes.

The more strange thing is when freeze happened, all of video players in other apps would freeze too (include safari), this state can not be restored unless reboot the device.

But I did not receive any AVPlayer error messages in that cases, everything seems OK.

Does anyone know what happened？

Comment: I have the same issue with local files